# " are replaced with ' with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

In ansible, I need to generate `daemon.json` file with log-opts:

```
{% if docker_log_dict is defined %}
  "log-opts": {{ docker_log_dict.log_opts | default('[]') }},
{% endif %}
```

With

```
log_opts: |
      {
        "syslog-address": "tcp://{{ my_ip_run }}:514",
        "tag": {% raw %}"{{.Name}}/{{.FullID}}"{% endraw %}
      }
```

But then, when I check the generated daemon.json file, I get :

```
...
"log_opts": 
      {
        'syslog-address': 'tcp://10.10.10.10:514',
        'tag': {% raw %}'{{.Name}}/{{.FullID}}'{% endraw %}
      }
```

Thing is when replacing, ansible is replacing with simple quote instead of double quotes.

When restarting Docker daemon, it will fail unless I use double quotes?

I don't understand why is that happening.

Anyone know how to fix it ???

Comment: How about `default("[]")` instead of `default('[]')`

Comment: yes, ok, but this is the case when `docker_log_dict.log_opts` is empty, but in my case, it it not empty, so it shouldn't affect me in this case. I will change it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a filter `to_json` in your Jinja template

```
{% if docker_log_dict is defined %}
  "log-opts": {{ docker_log_dict.log_opts | to_json | default('[]') }},
{% endif %}
```

I've found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/WUjiN9Wf32U